# enum name isnt allowed by compiler

Tags: java

So I had troubles with declaring enums in my program so I copied the code from the sun website example, at first the compiler was older then 1.5 so I updated it and the error changed to this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: examples.Day.values()[Lexamples/Day;
at examples.EnumTest.$SWITCH_TABLE$examples$Day(EnumTest.java:7)
at examples.EnumTest.tellItLikeItIs(EnumTest.java:15)
at examples.EnumTest.main(EnumTest.java:37)
```

my code:

```
import java.lang.Enum;
public enum Day {
SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY ;
}
public class EnumTest {
Day day;

public EnumTest(Day day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public void tellItLikeItIs() {
    switch (day) {
        case MONDAY:
            System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
            break;

        case FRIDAY:
            System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
            break;

        case SATURDAY:
        case SUNDAY:
            System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
    firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
    thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
    fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
    sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
    seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();
}
}
```

Comment: Just clean and recompile your project.

Comment: deleted the project and copied the code to another one, didnt help :)

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me.

Comment: @user3443891 - I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to your questions. Don't forget to upvote any answers that helped you and click the 'tick' to accept one answer as the most useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your enum declaration is wrong. Either put the whole declaration inside the EnumTest class as an inner class, remove the `public` specifier, or put it in a separate file.

Comment: @user3443891 Are you positive that the code compiled before you took the `public` out?  Or is it possible that you were getting a compilation error you didn't notice, and that the program that threw the `NoSuchMethodError` was an older one?  Please make sure you pay attention to details like this, otherwise you will confuse a lot of readers.